# How do I prevent the system's dark theme from changing the color of a View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-styles

So as an experiment, I have made a service that creates a little floating window rectangle that you can drag around the screen. It is supposed to be a  white rectangle with a black border.

Here is the layout for the view I am inflating with `LayoutInflater.inflate()`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/main_view"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_white"
        android:backgroundTint="@null" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is the xml for the drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

However, when I launch the service on my phone, the rectangle is not white, but dark gray/black (if my phone is in dark theme, which it usually is). The rectangle is white when my phone is in light theme. Here are a couple images to show the difference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IghsT.jpg

Even though I have explicitly stated the color of the drawable as a hex value as well as setting the background tint to `@null` and setting the layout theme to `@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light`, the rectangle is still dark when my phone is indark theme. How do I prevent the android system from changing the color of my View?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want dark mode, just put this line in your activity before setContentView().

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```